# ImportError: cannot import name 'saved_metadata_pb2' from 'tf_keras.protobuf' (unknown location)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, open-source, tf.keras

I am trying to contribute to tf-keras. Ihave forked it and cloned it to my local env. I have created a vertual environment and installed the dependencies from requirements.txt

then I have written a simple python file the first two line of which is

```
import tf_keras
from tf_keras import layers
```

this throws an error, namely:

```
ImportError: cannot import name ‘saved_metadata_pb2’ from ‘tf_keras.protobuf’ (unknown location)
```

any idea on what I am doing wrong?

moreover I would be greatful if you can explain how exactly to make changes in codes and see the effect of doing so.

when I make changes in a file. say if I canged Dense.py then if I import tf_keras.layers then will layers.Dense reflect that change. or do I have to someway build the keras using bezel and install it in someway.

Comment: It seems like there might be an issue with the installation or setup of your development environment. **ImportError: cannot import name ‘saved_metadata_pb2’ from ‘tf_keras.protobuf’ (unknown location**The error you're encountering suggests that there might be a problem with the import paths or the protobuf module.